# Pros and Cons of hashing password on DB or on API server interacting with db

Tags: hash, postgresql

I'm trying to understand what is good/bad about hashing a password on a database (like postgres) as opposed to hashing it on an api server and then sending it hashed to the db. Can anyone speak on this and the pros and cons of the security risk(s) of either implementation?

Comment: Usually you will want the database to store data, and the application server to process data.

Comment: Opinion based questions are off topic on this site.

Comment: How is it opinion based? One can give an objective and very helpful answer. "Which one is better" is opinion based. Pros and cons can be objective. (Unless you write "Pro: I like it", which is not helpful but not the problem of the question either.)